# recreational time or recreation time

Tags: word-choice

I think recreational time is better choice because "recreational" is an adjective. However, when I google it, I found that "recreation time" is rarely used, but I am not sure whether it is a correct compound noun, is it?

For example:

> **A person should have a recreational/recreation time on weekends.**

Comment: Could you provide a context, please?

Comment: Why do you think _recreation time_ is "rarely used"? How did you Google it? The [Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=recreation+time%2Crecreational+time&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15) would indicate that _recreational time_ is the lesser-used expression.

Comment: @J.R. obviously, I got an impression from google results, and I did not know about this nice tool :)

Comment: @Costa - Saying "I got an impression from google results" isn't all that informative. When you ask the community to answer questions for you, it's helpful when you provide as much information as you can. I'd still like to know what you Googled and what you saw that made you draw that conclusion. (Did you Google `recreation`? Or `recreation time`? Or `"recreation time"`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They both work, but "recreation time" is more likely.

Yes, it's a valid noun+noun phrase, meaning "time for recreation".